# Import XML files to MongoDb with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, io, mongodb

Here is my code which will read XML files and import the data to MongoDb. Do you have any comments on my code?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const log = console.log;
const path = require( "path" );

const folderPath = 'D:/Data';
const folder = folderPath;

fs.readdirSync(folder).forEach(file => {

    const extname = path.extname(file);
    const filename = path.basename(file, extname);
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(folder, file);

    const parser = new xml2js.Parser({
        mergeAttrs: true,
        explicitArray: false
    });

    fs.readFile(absolutePath, (err, data) => {

        parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {

            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
            var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

            MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                if (err) throw err;

                var dbo = db.db("myDb");

                dbo.collection("entity").insertMany(result, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    db.close();
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

I tested that it works for few files but for hundreds of files, it can throw an error.

Comment: What's the error it throws?

Comment: Connection time out. Should I post it to stack overflow instead?

Comment: Yeah sure,
I think your issue is with the fact you do your reading synchronously, thus blocking your main thread (and killing the process due to a timeout).

Try running it asynchronously first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Variable declaration keywords

One thing I notice is that the `var` keyword is used in some functions while others use `const`. The variables `dbo`, `MongoClient` and `url` are never reassigned so `const` can be used for those. Using `const` when re-assignment isn't needed is a good habit because it can help avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085). Many users also believe `var` should not be used with ES6 code - refer to the [ES lint rule `no-var`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var).

### nested callbacks

The code is bordering on [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com). I'd suggest moving anonymous functions out to being named functions. This will also help with automated testing. Let's look at the inner most function:

```
const insertionCallback = (db, err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;

    db.close();
};
```

It needs a reference to `db`. That could be made a parameter:

```
function (db, err, res) {
```

Then when making a reference to that function, make a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions) with `db` as the first argument:

```
dbo.collection("entity").insertMany(result, insertionCallback.bind(null, db))
```

Or instead of accepting `db` as a parameter, set the context to it:

```
dbo.collection("entity").insertMany(result, insertionCallback.bind(db))
```

after doing that `this` could be used instead of `db` within that `insertionCallback` function.

Then continue pulling out those nested functions - e.g. :

```
const insertResult = (result, err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const dbo = db.db("myDb");

    dbo.collection("entity").insertMany(result, insertionCallback.bind(null, db));
};
```

Then that function can be used in its outer function:

```
const handleParsedStr = (err, result) => {

    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    MongoClient.connect(url, insertResult.bind(null, result));
});
```

And that functions can be used as the callback to `parser.parseString()`:

```
parser.parseString(data, handleParsedStr);
```

### error handling

Some of the callback functions check error arguments like `err` and conditionally handle such cases, but others don't- e.g. the callback to `parser.parseString()`. It is advisable to handle such errors, and would also make the code more consistent.

### parser declared within forEach callback function

The variable `parser` is declared within the callback function to the `.forEach()` method. This means the parser is created once for each file in the directory. If possible, consider declaring it outside the loop to reduce resource requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive review. Learned much here :)